# Redirecionamento de de DNS para máquina da Amazon

Tags: amazon-aws, dns, route

Olá, tenho uma maquina EC2 na amazon, e contratei tbm o servico Route 53, criei uma hosted zone, com isso tive 4 endereços dns, coloquei isso no meu dominio e mesmo assim está aparecendo que a pagina nao está disponível, eu deve instalar um servidor de dns na maquina algo assim?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

depois de criar o hosted zone, com o nome do seu dominio, crie entradas do tipo CNAME e A, para o PUBLIC DNS e IP da sua VM, exemplo:

```
NAME                   TYPE   VALUE
seudominio.com.br       A      192.168.0.128
www.seudominio.com.br   CNAME  ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

O public DNS e o IP você pega no painel do EC2, logo após ter criado a VM

Agora dentro da VM, é preciso claro criar um ambiente web, você pode optar por nginx ou apache, dai ja é outra questão....

Também não esqueça de alterar o DNS de seu domínio, para os endereços de DNS criados pelo route53, e aguardar a propagação, que pode levar até umas 24h.

Comment: acredito que eu soh tenha esquecido de colocar as entradas CNAME e A, o resto ta blza, eu tenho o iis como servidor web e redirecionei os dns no dominio.

Comment: ah então acho q so faltou isso mesmo, testa ae, boa sorte

Comment: quanto a entrada CNAME eu tento criar somente com o nome do dominio aparece este erro: 
"RRSet of type CNAME with DNS name piscicontrol.com.br. is not permitted at apex in zone piscicontrol.com.br."

Comment: posé eu errei, editei a resposta, o CNAME é para nomes e não IP's, substitui pelo public DNS da tua vm, la no route53

Comment: Aproveitando a dúvida, William Borba, pode me explicar qual a diferença da entrada do tipo A para entrada do tipo CNAME. Quando uso cada uma delas?

Comment: CNAME(canonical name) são utilizadas para subdominios, no caso "www" é um subdominio de "seudominio.com.br" e entradas do tipo A são para IP de dominios puros, é o q eu sei, assim, mais ou menos rs